# Need to ensure a particular header file is always readonly when cloned from the Git repository

Tags: git

This particular (`*.hpp`) file will be autogenerated (say, appended) when certain other files are modified. I use a Python script to generate this file.

I don't want this file to be manually edited any moment in time.

My assumption was if I commit and push the particular file as read-only, and then retrieve it back it will still be read-only. Sadly this was not the case as Git doesn't remember the file mode.

Is there a way to ensure that the moment the project is cloned from the repository, this particular file will be made read-only? I am not sure if hooks can be used for this.

I am working with Tortoise Git, the latest version.

Comment: If it's automatically generated, does it need to be tracked at all?

Comment: As the python script which regenerates it, need the file  to be readonly whenever the file is accessed, But since by default the file from repository is read-write, the first time script will be used it will cry that some body has edited the file and will not proceed further

Comment: IF i can check before running the python script using some git command that if the file is the same as in repository .. then it can be readwrite. If the file has been modified by script,then i accept the file to be readonly. So a way to check if the file has changed (from python script) would be another option i feel.

Answer (score 0):

git doesn't track file permissions. you could just add it in .gitignore

```
echo "generated.hpp" >> .gitignore
```

If you don't have a `.gitignore` add this new file to the repository.

Comment: I am afraid i will be needing this file in repository, as i regenerate it based on what its last state is from repository + some other files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple console program to make that file read-only. Call it your own filter `MyReadOnly`.

Use something like this only for that repository: `git config filter.indent.smudge MyReadOnly`

cf. [Pro Git v2 - Keyword Expansion](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Git.

When you clone a repository, the hooks you've setup on the remote repository are not downloaded with the cloned repo, so the user would have to manually add the hook after cloning.

Your best bet is to:

- Alert the user that the file is auto-generated, to reduce the chance the user will modify it. Make it clear in the name of the file e.g. `MyFile.autogenerated.hpp` and stick a big comment at the top of the file with a "DO NOT EDIT - AUTOGENERATED" warning
- Run check(s) on your continuous integration server to auto-generate the file again, and compare against the file in Git, and fail the build if you notice any differences.